# ¿Como evitar que un <pre> genere scroll horizontal?

Tags: html, css

Tengo este fragmento `HTML` donde dentro de un `<pre>` imprimo con `Javascript` un `JSON`.

```css
pre {
  display: block;
  padding: 9.5px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<pre>{
  "info": {
    "lines": {
      "1": {
        "code": "1",
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 2.1,
        "title": "Item 1",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque nec risus in lacus commodo feugiat sit amet eget nibh. Phasellus in est at lectus varius blandit. Curabitur ut pellentesque libero, eget pulvinar nisi. Cras massa dui, congue vitae enim eget, mattis feugiat mi. Duis id dolor et turpis molestie mollis varius ac ipsum. Suspendisse rutrum neque in sagittis sodales. Sed enim leo, aliquet eget luctus nec, blandit ac sem.",
        "weight": 5,
        "cost": 0.7
      }
    }
  }
}</pre>
```

¿Que puedo hacer para que no se genere el scroll horizontal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aplicando [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) igual a `pre-wrap` pude solucionar mi problema.

> `pre-wrap`:
> Secuencias de espacio son preservadas. Lineas son rotas en caracteres de saltos de linea, en elementos html `<br>`, y agrega saltos necesarios para rellenar los cuadros de linea

**Demo:**

```css
pre {
  display: block;
  padding: 9.5px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: pre-wrap; /* ACA */
}
```

```html
<pre>{
  "info": {
    "lines": {
      "1": {
        "code": "1",
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 2.1,
        "title": "Item 1",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque nec risus in lacus commodo feugiat sit amet eget nibh. Phasellus in est at lectus varius blandit. Curabitur ut pellentesque libero, eget pulvinar nisi. Cras massa dui, congue vitae enim eget, mattis feugiat mi. Duis id dolor et turpis molestie mollis varius ac ipsum. Suspendisse rutrum neque in sagittis sodales. Sed enim leo, aliquet eget luctus nec, blandit ac sem.",
        "weight": 5,
        "cost": 0.7
      }
    }
  }
}</pre>
```